# How to use ActiveDirectory with Spring-Security LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to setup Spring Security for LDAP authentication on my Spring MVC application.  I can't seem to get the simple/principal authentication to work with the LdapAuthenticationProvider, so I'm trying to use the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider, which does it by default.

I get a NameNotFoundException with the detailMessage after the context is created (and I think LDAP bind has occurred), from this line (310 in ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java):

```
return SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(context,
                searchControls, searchRoot, searchFilter,
                new Object[] { bindPrincipal });
```

Error message:

```
[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'DC=my,DC=company,DC=com']
```

The search filter is looking for an object with class "user" with a userPrincipalName equal to the username I authenticated with, and concatenated with the domain name for my domain.  For example, "me@my.company.com".  The attribute with that value exists, as I can authenticate with JXplorer in this method, and subsequently perform that search to find my user object.

The configuration for my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter subclass, where I wire in an AuthenticationManagerBuilder, is basically this:

```
@Autowired
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("my.company.com", "LDAPS://ad.my.company.com:636/dc=my,dc=company,dc=com");
   provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
   auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}
```

What is causing the NameNotFoundException?  Is this the proper way to configure ActiveDirectory Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face palm. The URL of the LDAP server should not include the X.501 domain component part, at least in my directory's case. I guess that makes sense as the first constructor argument is the domain's name (in FQDN style). So the constructor arguments should then be...

```
new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("my.company.com", "ldaps://ad.my.company.com:636");
```

The error message hinted at this, as the bind completed, but the search failed. The exact error had " NO_OBJECT" as the reason, which was the clue that the search base was off. My originally configured search essentially added the search base (DCs) twice.